# Images not displaying at all on mobile, but work fine on desktop

Tags: html, laravel-5.6

My images are displaying correctly on desktop but not on mobile. If you request desktop site on mobile browser, they show.

Any thoughts?

Here is the website: [Website here](https://www.crypto-bids.co.uk)

**here is the html head code outputted by the blade template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
content="default-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' *.fontawesome.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' *.fontawesome.com https://fonts.gstatic.com;
script-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-EDNnf03nceIOfn39fn3e9h3sdfa' *.pusher.com; connect-src 'self' *.pusher.com wss://ws-eu.pusher.com;"
>
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="qib265IRboiaWoQEKLlPEta69HaxCmxPqz1bBAOQ">

    <title>Crypto Bids</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.crypto-bids.co.uk/images/bids-favicon.png">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="https://www.crypto-bids.co.uk/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3AB7yXWz4OeoZcPbieVW64vVXEwADiYyAEhwilzWsLw+9FgqpyjjStpPnpBO8o8S" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="https://www.crypto-bids.co.uk/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link src="https://www.crypto-bids.co.uk/css/cookieconsent.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://www.crypto-bids.co.uk/css/cart.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://www.crypto-bids.co.uk/css/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://www.crypto-bids.co.uk/js/head.js"></script>
</head>
```

**And here is an example of an image:**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <img src="https://www.crypto-bids.co.uk/images/logo-top-beta.png" />
</a>
```

**and, how it appears in the b;lade template:**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <img src="{{ asset('/images/logo-top-beta.png') }}" />
</a>
```

If i visit the image URL directly, the image shows, but not on the page itself - my brain is telling me it could be something in the `<head>` tags.

I have been scratching my head over this for a while now, anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this is not truly an answer, but an update. The problem just magically went away after hours of comparing html code - very very odd